# The Rotation in iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, rotation, ios8

I have just upgraded to Xcode 6 and when running my app in iphone 6(ios8) the screen sometimes cannot rotate. This issue is not happen in ios 7. I searched in the internet and see `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` is deprecated in ios 8. Current my code is implementing this function, if i replace it with new funcion `viewWillTransitionToSize`, the app runs on ios7 will not be affect ?

I can call the `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` as below

```
[self willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:interfaceOrientation duration:0.0];
```

But i don't know how to call `viewWillTransitionToSize`

```
[self viewWillTransitionToSize:<#(CGSize)#> withTransitionCoordinator:<#(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)#>]
```

What should I send `CGSize`  and `UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator` in this function? Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to call these methods manually?

Answer (score 2):

Hope you have set the below items in project->general tab.
[image]

AND you just give this

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
   return YES;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
   return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
   return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait |UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown;
    //or simply UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

Happy Coding :)